Strictly increasing family of sets $\mathcal{E_j}$ which consists of countable unions of sets in $\mathcal{E}_{j-1}$ or their complements
In Folland's Real Analysis, Section 1.6, it says

Our characterization of the $\sigma$-algebra
$\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$ generated by a family $\mathcal{E} \subset
 \mathcal{P}(X)$ is nonconstructive, and one might ask how to obtain
$\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$ explicitly from $\mathcal{E}$. The answer
is rather complicated. One can begin as follows: Let $\mathcal{E}_1 =
 \mathcal{E} \cup \{E^c : E \in \mathcal{E}\}$, and for $j > 1$ define
$\mathcal{E}_j$ to be the collection of all sets that are countable
unions of sets in $\mathcal{E}_{j-1}$ or complements of such. Let
$\mathcal{E}_\omega = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \mathcal{E}_j$; is
$\mathcal{E}_\omega = \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$? In general, no.
$\mathcal{E}_\omega$ is closed under complements, but if $E_j \in
 \mathcal{E}_j \setminus \mathcal{E}_{j-1}$ for each $j$, there is no
reason for $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j$ to be in $\mathcal{E}_\omega$.
So one must start all over again.

Is there a simple example of a family of sets $\mathcal{E}$ such that the resulting sets  $(\mathcal{E_j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ (as defined above) are strictly increasing? If $\mathcal{E}$ is the family of open intervals (or closed / half open - whatever is easier), are the sets $\mathcal{E_j}$ strictly increasing? If so what's an example of a set $E \in \mathcal{E_j} \setminus \mathcal{E_{j-1}}$ for any $j \in \mathbb{N}$?

It is strictly increasing in case of the family of open intervals. A slight modification of this process is known as the Borel hierarchy. And it is known that the levels of the Borel hierarchy are strictly increasing. (Though I’m not sure how to write down explicit examples of $E \in \mathcal{E}j \setminus \mathcal{E}{j-1}$, except for the smallest few $j$.)
